# Application of Kolmogorov's Zero-One Law

Tags: probability-theory

Most of the books I read, they only state some examples of tail events. One of them is
 $[\sum_n X_n \ converges]$. My main problem is to show that this is indeed a tail event.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_n^{(k)}=X_{n+k}$, $B=\left[\sum\limits_nX_n\ \text{converges}\right]$ and $B_k=\left[\sum\limits_nX_n^{(k)}\ \text{converges}\right]$. Then, for every $k\geqslant0$, the event $B_k$ is in $\sigma(X_n^{(k)};n\geqslant0)=\sigma(X_n;n\geqslant k)$ and $B=B_k$, QED.